# Submitting gridview through jquery

Tags: c#, .net, jquery

Hi I have an excel or can use csv file with three columns. Name, Age & City. I am getting the data as Datatable than binding it as Gridview to display on the page. Than I want to take that gridview as a whole table or iterate through each row and process in my process.cs through jquery  to write to the database.  My problem is with jquery, it is not working correctly.

Code behind the Binding to gridview:

```
GridView1.DataSource = primeSupplier.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

On aspx page I have:

```
<form id="mainForm" runat="server">
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 310px; overflow:scroll">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="6" CellSpacing="5"   AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"   >
      </asp:GridView>     
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
          var sTempVal = null;

          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#GridView1").ajaxSubmit(
              "./folder1/process.aspx"
              , function (response) {
                                    ji('Success'
                     , 
                     , function () {
                         ("./");
                     }
                  );
              });
          });
```

The jquery function submitting with #GridView1 is not working. I am trying to either pass the whole gridview or iterate through each row and write it to database. Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: i'm afraid you going in a wrong way, .net controls and jquery dont go hand in hand.

Comment: Just an observation, but why use AJAX if you're posting the entire form anyway? Surely `<button type="submit"></button>` would be a hell of a lot easier? Anyway, the `.ajaxSubmit()` (you should mention you're using the jQuery Form Plugin) looks fine syntactically. What's the `ji()` function?